# Azure AD how to prevent app users from login into azure portal

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am using ADAL to auth mobile app users to my Azure AD and that works fine, but the flip side to the coin is that they can also login to portal.azure.com, how can I prevent that? I don't want users to have access to my azure portal at all, only the apps I grant them access to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a portal setting: Portal.Azure.com > Azure Active Directory > User Settings > Administration portal > **Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal (Yes/No).**

*No lets a non-administrator use this Azure AD administration portal experience to access Azure AD resources that the user has permission to read, or manage resources they own. Yes restricts all non-administrators from accessing any Azure AD data in the administration portal, but does not restrict such access using PowerShell  or another client such as Visual Studio*.

Comment: It looks like this only stops user from accessing the Azure AD portal. How do you stop them from accessing the entire Azure portal.